# Ionic .showAddPopup not saving and sending data to Parse

Tags: angularjs, cordova, parse-platform, ionic-framework

Been going through a tutorial on ionic and created an app with a popup with a few text fields, it works but the ok button does nothing when pressed and it should send the filled in data to my Parse database but doesn't. I've gone over the code a few times but not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is my [js file with the function in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hScox.png), and my corresponding [index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bia9.png). I think the error is in the friend.save because the error log shows issues with personEmail, personContact, etc., but not sure how to fix it. (Please note: very new to this/development).

JS file:

```
$scope.showAddPopup : function () {
    var myPopup : $ionicPopup.sbow({
        template : '<input type= "text" placebolder="Name" ng-model="new.personName"/><br/>
        <input type= "text" placeholder="Phone" ng-model="new.personContact"/><br/>
        <input type: "text" placeholder="Email" ng-model="new.personEmail"/><br/>
        <input type= "text" placeholder="Display Picture URL" ng-model="new.personDisplayPicture"/>'.
        title : 'Enter Details',
        subtitle : '',
        scope : $scope,
        buttons : [{
                text : 'Cancel'
            }, {
                text : 'OK',
                type : 'button-assertive',
                onTap : function (e) {
                    var newFriend = Parse.object.extend('friendslist');
                    var friend = new newFriend();
                    friend.save({
                        personName: $scope.new.personNane,
                        personEmail: $scope.new.personEnail,
                        personContact: $scope.new.personContact,
                        personDisplayPicture: $scope.new.personDisplayPicture
                    }).then(function (object) {
                        $ionicPopup.alert({
                            title : 'Friend Added',
                            template : 'Friend has been successfully added to the list.’
                            });
                    })
                }
            }]
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please don't attach code as picture but share sample of verifiable code (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @beaver thank you for letting me know and the link on how to provide code, will follow that. It worked up until a point and now is not. I am new to all of this and really not sure where it went wrong, so in that case how do I show verifiable code or the code I think is the issue if I have no idea where the problem lies? Shouldn't I show a lot of my index and js files in this situation? All the code in the links create the problem when I run it. Thanks again.

Comment: Code samples should be text not pictures... I edited your question converting your JS into text formatted as code. Please do the same with HTML.

Comment: @beaver thank you for doing that! Ok, will do (I actually may have figured it out so checking that first and then will post if not), thanks again.